# How to have anchor and data-toggle in rails 4 link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, bootstrap-tabs

So I am running rails 4 and trying to get a *link_to* working a bit better, using *link_to* so I can have params define, instead of doing:

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if params[:active_tab] == 'users' || params[:active_tab].blank? %>">
<a href='#user" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>
```

Which produces:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#users-tab" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>
```

Currently I have:

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if params[:active_tab] == 'users' || params[:active_tab].blank? %>">
<%= link_to "Users", :anchor => 'users-tab',  :active_tab => 'users', :data => { :toggle => 'tab'} %></li>
```

Which is producing:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/admin?active_tab=users&amp;data%5Btoggle%5D=tab#users-tab">Users</a></li>
```

Does anyone have a better way of doing this get get a result similar to:

```
<li class="active"><a href="admin?active_tab=users" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to make sure you separate the hashes

```
<%= link_to "Users", { :anchor => 'users-tab',  :active_tab => 'users' }, { :data => { :toggle => 'tab'} } %></li>
```